# How can I show a count value in SQL instead of listing out many rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: Exam, Objective and Test.

- An exam can have zero or many Objectives
- An exam can have zero or many Tests

I created this SQL to report on the data:

```
SELECT name, objectiveId, TestId
FROM exam
LEFT JOIN Test ON Test.ExamId = Exam.ExamId
LEFT JOIN Objective ON Objective.ExamId = Exam.ExamId
```

What I would like to do is instead of showing the objectiveId and TestId then I would
like to show a count of how many objectives or tests there are for each exam. Something
like:

```
Exam    Objectives   Tests
Exam1            1      10
Exam2            2       0
```

Comment: Did you try using, I dunno, the `COUNT` function?

Comment: However, if you use the count() function you will need to provide a group by on testID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT name Exam, COALESCE(COUNT(objectiveId), 0) Objectives, COALESCE(COUNT(TestId), 0) Tests
FROM exam
LEFT JOIN Test ON Test.ExamId = Exam.ExamId
LEFT JOIN Objective ON Objective.ExamId = Exam.ExamId
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Is coalesce necessary?

Comment: @Tim, NULL is the result if there are no - for example - objectives. COALESCE maps NULL -> 0

Comment: To be precise (and picky): `COALESCE` maps NULL to whatever you state. `COALESCE (A,B,C,D...)` will return the first non-null value of `A,B,C,D`.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with a way for count to return null. It should just return a zero if there are no objectives.